# MD5 string not displaying correctly with html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cryptojs

I have two spans with the IDs `salt` and `password`

```
<div>
    $salt = '<span id="salt"></span>';<br />
    $password = '<span id="password"></span>';
</div>
```

I then use the following jQuery code which takes the salt, adds it to the password entered by the user, and returns both a salt and hashed password (to copy into a config file)

```
salt = (Math.random() +1).toString(36).substr(2, 16);
$('#salt').html(salt);
hashed = CryptoJS.MD5(salt + $(this).val());
$('#password').html(hashed);
```

This code adds the salt to the span with the `salt` ID, but it doesn't add anything to the `password` ID.

If I enter the code `alert(hashed)` it will open an alert with an md5 value.

If I change `.html()` to `.text()` it works.

Comment: is there any other element with the id password in the page

Comment: Don't beg bugs/limits. And use [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and *not* `.html` because MD5 is not HTML. In any case, *as long as neither `&` or `<` occur* they should have equivalent results.

Comment: can you see the value of `$('[id="password"]').length`

Comment: there is only the input which has the attribute `id="password-input"` and yes I can see the length (since my function only runs if the password is >= 6 chars

Comment: @user2864740 wow, `.text()` works without changing anything else.

Comment: also, I changed the title (had to google what "don't beg bugs" meant first) :)

Comment: @cantsay Now you know the answer :) But a decent initial title would be something like "MD5 string not displaying correctly with html()" - then after observing the results a reason/limitation and solution (ie. answer) is proposed.

Comment: Using MD5 for anything cryptographic and sensitive like passwords is **totally insane**. Please, switch to something sensible like SHA1 or SHA256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `CryptoJS.MD5()` method returns an object. to convert this object to a string use it's `toString()` method.

```
hashed = CryptoJS.MD5(value);
var hashedString = hashed.toString();
```

than to insert the text into an element use jQuerys `text()` method. the jQuery `html()` method is for setting an elements `innerHTML` value. but you want to insert unescaped text.

```
$('#password').text(hashedString);
```

*if an object is passed to `text()` it will automatically call `toString()` on it, although this is not documented in the reference*

## reference

### .text( text )

> The text to set as the content of each matched element. When Number or Boolean is supplied, it will be converted to a String representation. **[…] be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML.**

*from [jQuery API Documentation: `text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)*

### .html( htmlString )

> A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element

*from [jQuery API Documentation: `html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)*

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this doesn't explain why `html()` outputs the `salt` (which is an alnum string) but not `hashed` (which is also an alnum string)

Comment: here's your answer. edited the post. hope it clarifies things.